# System.AccessViolationException in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to trace down this error or even trap it to prevent it from crashing the application.  The application is written in VB.NET using .NET 4.

```
Application: Satcom Discovery Socket.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods+SafeNetHandles.closesocket(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.SafeCloseSocket+InnerSafeCloseSocket.ReleaseHandle()
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousRelease()
   at System.Net.SafeCloseSocket.CloseAsIs()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Dispose(Boolean)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Dispose()
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Close(Int32)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Dispose(Boolean)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Close(Boolean)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Dispose(Boolean)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Close()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CloseFully()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Close()
   at SatcomDiscoverySocket.modDatabase.DeleteStatus(SatcomDiscoverySocket.Status ByRef, Int32)
   at SatcomDiscoverySocket.frmSocket.TimerSocketConn_Tick(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(System.EventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer+TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(System.String[])
   at SatcomDiscoverySocket.My.MyApplication.Main(System.String[])
```

The other error from the event logs is

> Faulting application name: Satcom Discovery Socket.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5465cfdd
>   Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18247, time stamp: 0x521ea8e7
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x0002e3be
>   Faulting process id: 0x94c
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d004411406ec37
>   Faulting application path: D:\SocketDaemon\Satcom Discovery Socket.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
>   Report Id: 2cefa3fd-70d4-11e4-8cc0-002219a5cbd1

Any ideas?

I thought I had the unhandled exceptions trapped with the following code

```
            'for regular unhandled stuff 
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MYGeneralExceptionHandler
        'for threads behind forms 
        AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf MyThreadExceptionHandler
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: `AppDomain.UnhandledException` is called when an unhandled exception occurs, but you cannot trap or avoid the exception in any way with it. And that's a good thing, because an `AccessViolationException` indicates a serious problem interacting with unmanaged code. Are you using the most recent version of the MySql connector? Any assemblies with unmanaged code you're referencing that could be likely candidates for trouble?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I would have thought that the function MYGeneralExceptionHandler would be called which emails me the error with the full description and hopefully indicates the cause.  Am I assuming incorrect?  I dont have the latest mySQL connector, I believe I'm on 6.4.4.  do you think that's its related to mySQL?

Comment: If an unhandled exception occurs in the CLR itself, your application is terminated immediately without any managed code running afterwards, including any exception handlers. There is, unfortunately, nothing more you can do in that case.

Comment: I don't know if the MySQL connector is the problem, but it appears to be (stress *appears to be*) the only third-party code that could cause an issue. Other potential causes are a bug in the CLR itself (rare but not unheard of, check if you have the most recent updates) or a rogue DLL injected in your application that is screwing you over. You could try running it on a clean machine (no software installed but .NET and your service).

Comment: This is an environmental problem, closing a socket of course should never crash your program.  The source of such a crash is the cr*ppy code that hangs off sockets that you didn't write and is not normally installed on an operating system.  Anti-malware, firewall, usage monitor, that kind of badware.  Aggressively clean up your machine.

Comment: Thanks you all for the advise, I'll try and update the mySQL connector files and see how that goes!